# Failed to work with multiple WSDLs using Python zeep

Tags: python, soap, wsdl, zeep

I have WSDL service which provides several links like

```
http://localhost:8081/View1&Wsdl
...
http://localhost:8081/ViewN&Wsdl
```

But the problem is that I can't work with multiple WSDL links using zeep library (2.5.0)

My code:

```
import zeep

view1_wsdl = 'http://localhost:8081/View1&Wsdl'
client1 = zeep.Client(wsdl=view1_wsdl)
result1 = client1.service.method1()
print(result1) 

view2_wsdl = 'http://localhost:8081/View2&Wsdl'
client2 = zeep.Client(wsdl=view2_wsdl)
result2 = client2.service.method2()
print(result2)
```

I get correct result1, but there's error with result2:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/.../auto_tests/wsdl_check.py", line 17, in <module>
    result2 = client2.service.method2
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\client.py", line 45, in __call__
    self._op_name, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 110, in send
options=options)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 68, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py", line 197, in create
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 63, in serialize
    body_value = self.body(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\elements\element.py", line 48, in __call__
    instance = self.type(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\types\complex.py", line 42, in __call__
    return self._value_class(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 90, in __init__
    items = _process_signature(self._xsd_type, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\...\lib\site-packages\zeep\xsd\valueobjects.py", line 194, in _process_signature
    len(result), num_args))
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 0 positional arguments (1 given)
```

How can I deal with it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you haven't already, please feel free to check out [how to ask](//stackoverflow.com/help/ask) and [what's on-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1):

The problem was in WSDL service, not in `zeep` lib.

Comment: This should be a comment. Answers need to have sufficient information to understand the answer. The answer should be described in a reasonable level of detail and / or include a minimal example of the answer.